# Custom Variable not compiled

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm making a simple project on Symfony, I'm using webpack to add bootstrap and I'm trying to add some customs variable but it doens't compile when I do a `yarn build`

How do you compile custom variable to the build folder ?

My app.scss

```
$nav: #F4F4F4;
$footer: #F76C6C;

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I'm trying to chnag emy nav color but when I put my variable name its doesn't show the customs but just the default ones like primary

my navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo-wild.png') }}" alt="" width="70" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
            Les Argonautes
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `yarn build` probably translates to `yarn encore production --progress` which is only going to work in production. If you are working in `dev` then you probably want `yarn dev`

Answer (score 0):

The variables `$nav` and `$footer` do not exist in bootstrap so defining them won't do anything. To change the color of your navbar take a look at these sections from the documentation:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#variables